# How to refine my jQuery code so that it can narrow down and show( filter ) specific content

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to refine my code so that i can get more precise results when filtering? For example when you check RTS(strategy games) and on PC , you want to get strategy games for PC(you should get StarCraft), but im getting all games for PC and strategy, so thats just adding to the pool of games not narrowing down... thanks in advance for any input.

Can someone give some pointers on how to refine my code so that i can get more precise results when filtering? For example when you check RTS(strategy games) and on PC , you want to get strategy games for PC(you should get StarCraft), but im getting all games for PC and strategy, so thats just adding to the pool of games not narrowing down... thanks in advance for any input.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/azaoPj

```
<div id="container">

  <div id="filter">
    <h3>Filter By</h3>
    <div class="category-filters"><img id="reset" src="http://www.asus.com/media/images/rest.png" alt="" />Reset</div>
    <div class="category-filters">
      <div class="genre">
        <img src="http://www.asus.com/media/images/close_round.png" id="open" class="col"/> Genre
      </div>

      <div id="genre-filters">
        <ul  class="filter-options">
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_action" data-filter_id="action"> Action</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_fps" data-filter_id="fps"> FPS</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_rpg" data-filter_id="rpg"> RPG<li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_rts" data-filter_id="rts"> RTS</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_adventure" data-filter_id="adventure"> Adventure</li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="category-filters">
      <div class="brand">
        <img src="http://www.asus.com/media/images/close_round.png" id="open" class="col1"/> Platform
      </div>

      <div id="brand-filters" class="category-filters">
        <ul  class="filter-options">
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_pc" data-filter_id="pc"> PC</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_ps3" data-filter_id="ps3"> PS3</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_ps4" data-filter_id="ps4"> PS4<li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_x360" data-filter_id="x360"> Xbox 360</li>
          <li><input type="checkbox" value="filter_xone" data-filter_id="xone"> Xbox one</li>
        </ul>
      </div> 
    </div>

  </div>


  <div id="products">
    <ul id="product-list">

      <li class="filter_pc filter_fps filter_xone">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcRq1K6i1syrOr20l1k43vcJCSjeMHJP7c0w-xS-xmpSUPM1EuGGLPNI73gox8cbJX9k0tlRtvfm&usqp=CAE" alt="" />
      </li>
      <li class="filter_action filter_adventure filter_pc filter_ps3 filter_x360">
        <img src="http://s4.thcdn.com/productimg/0/300/300/52/10780752-1370965433-955769.jpg" alt="" />  
      </li>
      <li class="filter_fps filter_pc filter_ps3 filter_x360">
        <img src="http://s2.thcdn.com/productimg/0/300/300/42/10846642-1389618973-536407.jpg" alt="" />
      </li>  
      <li class="filter_rts filter_pc">
        <img src="http://s2.thcdn.com/productimg/0/300/300/01/10654001-1353502110-933610.jpg" alt="" />
      </li>
      <li class="filter_rpg filter_ps4">
        <img src="http://s2.thcdn.com/productimg/0/180/180/92/10968092-1422879679-941767.jpg" alt="" />
      </li>
    </ul> 

  </div>

</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $(".filter-options :checkbox").click(function(){
    $("#product-list li").hide();
    $(".filter-options :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
      $("." + $(this).val()).fadeIn();
    });
    if ($('.filter-options :checkbox').filter(':checked').length == 0 ) {
      $("#product-list li").fadeIn();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So at the moment you are fading in all items with a class equal to the `.val()` of *any* of the checkboxes. What you really want to do is add the selectors together to get a selector that only chooses an element with all the desired class names.

In CSS this is really easy, a selector like this is what you are after:

```
.filter_pc.filter_fps
```

So we need to create that with jQuery by adding the individual values together — something like this:

```
var search = '';
$(".filter-options :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
  search += '.' + $(this).val(); // Add each val to the current search
});
// By this stage search will be equal to '.filter_pc.filter_fps'
// Now do the search
$(search).fadeIn();
```

So for each item you are concatenating the search, adding each class name with a dot in front of it. The CSS selector then will refer specifically to an item with all those classes.

Here is a demo:
http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/ogPjwv

Comment: I have a little problem :(, after some time of testing i think this way cant show more than 2 categories or sometimes shows only 1, for example if you click on Action and FPS games , you should get 3 games, this way its only showing the first class of the clicked checkbox. Another example if you check Action and RTS you should get Assassins Creed + StarCraft.

Comment: if i click action and rts I don't get any games that are `filter_action filter_adventure filter_pc filter_ps3 filter_x360`... which is what assassins creed is. Try adding filter_rts to assassins creed